# How to use locks without causing deadlock in concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrent.futures

I'm processing Jira changelog history data, and due to the large amount of data, and the fact that most of the processing time is I/O based, I figured that an asynchronous approach might work well.

I have a list of all `issue_id`'s, which I'm feeding into a function that makes a request through the `jira-python` api, extracts the information into a `dict`, and then writes it out through a passed in `DictWriter`.  To make it threadsafe I imported a `Lock()` from the `threading` module, which I am also passing in.  On testing, it seems to get deadlocked at a certain point and just hangs.  I noticed in the documentation where it said that if tasks are reliant on one another then they can hang, and I suppose they are due to the lock I'm implementing.  How can I prevent this from happening?

Here is my code for reference:

(At this point in the code there is a list called `keys` with all the issue_id's)

```
def write_issue_history(
        jira_instance: JIRA,
        issue_id: str,
        writer: DictWriter,
        lock: Lock):
    logging.debug('Now processing data for issue {}'.format(issue_id))
    changelog = jira_instance.issue(issue_id, expand='changelog').changelog

    for history in changelog.histories:
        created = history.created
        for item in history.items:
            to_write = dict(issue_id=issue_id)
            to_write['date'] = created
            to_write['field'] = item.field
            to_write['changed_from'] = item.fromString
            to_write['changed_to'] = item.toString
            clean_data(to_write)
            add_etl_fields(to_write)
            print(to_write)
            with lock:
                print('Lock obtained')
                writer.writerow(to_write)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as outf:
                writer = DictWriter(
                    f=outf,
                    fieldnames=fieldnames,
                    delimiter='|',
                    extrasaction='ignore'
                )
                writer_lock = Lock()
                with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as exec:
                    for key in keys[:5]:
                        exec.submit(
                            write_issue_history,
                            j,
                            key,
                            writer,
                            writer_lock
                        )
```

EDIT: It's also very possible I'm being throttled by the Jira API.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the result of `exec` into a list, conventionally named `futs`, and then loop through that list calling `result()` to get their result, handling any errors that might have happened.

(I'd also chance `exec` to `executor` as that's more conventional and it avoids overriding the built-in)

```
from traceback import print_exc

...

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    futs = []
    for key in keys[:5]:
        futs.append( executor.submit(
            write_issue_history,
            j,
            key,
            writer,
            writer_lock)
        )

for fut in futs:
    try:
        fut.result()
    except Exception as e:
        print_exc()
```